# Flag a cell if it contains a partial text from a master list

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

In list A I have a list of 'do not contact' email addresses that has just the @xyz.com email ID's. This is the 'master list'.

In list B I have a bunch of emails I received.

I want to somehow flag those emails in list B that contain the @ email ID's from column A so I can remove them from list B.

Comment: `=IF(COUNTIF(C13:C14,MID(E13,FIND("@",E13),999))>0,TRUE,FALSE)`  C13:C14 would be list A, and E13 would be the cell in list B that is being tested.  You could enter this in for conditional formatting to flag the cell itself.

Comment: @ScottCraner -  The `IF(<formula>, TRUE, FALSE)` wrapper can be discarded as a CF rule only cares if something is true or false. A zero is False and anything that is not False is True. e.g. `=COUNTIF(C13:C14,MID(E13,FIND("@",E13),99))` although as a CF rule formula, some of the cell address should have $ added judiciously.

Comment: @Jeeped I added that last line as a second thought.  Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand, assuming list A is in ColumnA and list B in ColumnB starting below the end of list A, please select ColumnB and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=MATCH(MID(B1,FIND("@",B1),LEN(B1)),A:A,0)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select colour fill, OK, OK. Then filter on colour to select and delete the relevant rows, or flag these to sort and move them.